# Using Mailto in react

Tags: reactjs, mailto

I am using Mailto to send a mail from react.

```html
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function Mailto({ email, subject, body, ...props }) {
  return (
    <a href={`mailto:${email}?subject=${subject || ""}&body=${body || ""}`}>
      {props.children}
    </a>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Mailto email="sample@gmail.com" subject="Working" body="Hey there !">
    Mail me!
  </Mailto>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

But this function triggers a draft mail and it is storing in the draft of sender mailbox. I have to go inside the draft box and send the mail for it to go to reciever.

Is that the functionality of Mailto or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the RFC: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6068

Specifically, [section 3: Semantics and Operations](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6068#section-3) includes this (emphasis mine):

> The operation of how any URI scheme is resolved is not mandated by
> the URI specifications.  In current practice, resolving URIs such as
> those in the 'http' URI scheme causes an immediate interaction
> between client software and a host running an interactive server.
> The 'mailto' URI has unusual semantics because resolving such a URI
> does not cause an immediate interaction with a server.  Instead, the
> client creates a message to the designated address with the various
> header fields set as default.  **The user can edit the message, send
> the message unedited, or choose not to send the message.**

Also — you didn't ask about this — but I suggest that you read the specifications for valid encoding. Directly including JS strings in template literals can result in invalid URIs.

Comment: so using Mailto I can't send mail directly. Only it will create a draft mail to the senders account and the sender has to go and send.

Comment: Is there any other solutions for sending mail from frontend?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73795762/using-mailto-in-react/73795802?noredirect=1#comment130307303_73795802) @KaranS That's correct. The user's email client controls that behavior (not your React app or the `mailto` URI scheme).

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73795762/using-mailto-in-react/73795802?noredirect=1#comment130307308_73795802) @KaranS That's a separate question than the one you asked. You are welcome to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).